# Flutter iOS: The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

So i know this has been asked before but none of the answers work for me.
When i run the command 'flutter run' i get the following error:
' Error 0xe8008018: The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid. AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication(0, device, url, options, install_callback, 0)'

When i run from XCode everything works as expected.
I tried everything i could find on the web, like deleting and re-adding profisioning profiles,
changing team, redownloading certificates and upping the version number of the app.

Dont know what to try anymore, all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Try cleaning your project directory with `flutter clean` and deleting your app on the device, then run your app again. I had the same issue and doing this solved the problem.